# Custom Non Alt Shortcuts for QMenu

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMenuBar with some QMenus.  For example,

```
QMenu* menu = myMainWindow->menubar()->addMenu(tr("Settings"));
```

Now, I know that if I add an ampersand, say "&Settings", I can open this menu using alt+S.  However, my application requires usage of custom keys. Moreover, in my application, we don't even have an "alt" key. Anyhow, for example of custom key, we take an unused location in Qt::Key (specifically what is considered an unknown key), and use them for events.  This works fine normally.  In fact, something like this typically works:

```
int val = keyEvent->key();
if (key == MyCustomKeyEnum::CustomKey)
   // do stuff
```

But, how do I set a menu to have a custom int key shortcut?  Or, equivalently, how can I open a menu from a menubar programatically? I can trivially connect an event from MyCustomKeyEnum::CustomKey to a custom slot. So, perhaps I can potentially avoid a shortcut custom key in the first place?

I tried to use targetMenu.exec(), but because I'd like to be able to use the arrow keys to navigate to adjacent menus, and have the menu spawned in the right position, this was not a good option.

Answer (score 0):

After combing the documentation meticulously, I found the correct function in [QMenuBar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenubar.html#setActiveAction)-- setActiveAction.

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to easily select your action via the API by menu name. So, you have to do so manually.

```
for (QAction* act : menuBar()->actions())
{
    if (act->text() == tr("Settings"))
    {
        menuBar()->setActiveAction(act);
    }
}
```

, and then have this function itself called by the keyboard event handler.

However, if you have a pointer to the desired menu, you can call [menuAction()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#menuAction), and this becomes much simpler.

```
menuBar()->setActiveAction(mySettingsMenu->menuAction());
```

Hope this saves someone else from searching an insane amount of time, like myself, in the future.